# How to strore multiple rows in a variable in sql server08

Tags: sql-server

I want to know, How can I store multiple rows in a variable.i.e. My query will return multiple rows and i want to store it in a variable.
Thanks in adv.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What you're planning to do with those rows influences the best answer for how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SQL Server 2008, there's a feature called **[Table Valued Parameters](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters)** which allow you to store rows into a variable that can be passed across stored procedures.

If however, your intent is to manipulate the data inside the same store procedure, then common table variables would be fine. Here's an Example:

```
DECLARE @MyTableVariable TABLE
(
  Id int,
  FirstName varchar(10),
  LastName varchar(10)
);

INSERT @MyTableVariable(Id, FirstName, LastName)
SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName FROM SomeOtherTable WHERE SomeCriteria
```

`@MyTableVariable` now contains all the rows matching the criteria, you can still continue to add more rows, do further manipulations and even return its contents.

Comment: Also, Table Valued Parameters are available in SQL Server 2005 as well.

Comment: @Nick - Table Valued Parameters do no exist in SQL Server 2005. Read this: http://dotnethitman.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!E149A8B1E1C25B14!222.entry

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [table valued parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) or you can use the old stand-by temp tables.